# ReadProccessMemory with C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am writing a program that creates a process and then read some bits of his memory. To get the address, I used the debugger OllyDbg.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace winapi
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
          IntPtr hProcess,
          IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
          [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
          int dwSize,
          out UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesRead
         );


        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WinAPI test");
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine();

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "Program.exe" };
            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            var bytes = new byte[4];
            uint read = 0;
            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            //  

            while (read == 0)
            {
                ReadProcessMemory(p.MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)0x052f820, bytes, bytes.Length, out read);    
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(read.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

after the process started, my loop never ends.
data from the debugger:

```
0052F820 | 75 2F 3F 72 61 67 65 5F 69 64 3D 31 33
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: According to the documentation, if the function fails, it returns 0. You're not checking the return value, are you sure it is succeeding? If not, I'm sure *it* would be able to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Also note that the memory address can be completely different every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is already provided by @zmbq. ReadProcessMemory does not behave like Stream, where every read operation adds the total read count to the stream position.

I can still see another problem with the code, you are passing **Window handle** instead of the **process handle**. So even if you get the result, it is not actually reading memory of your target process.

Comment: Thanks! I changed `p.MainWindowHandle` to `p.Handle` and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it end? You're reading the same 4 bytes over and over again. ReadProcessMemory doesn't work like a stream does.

Comment: lpNumberOfBytesRead returns count of readed bytes. If count = 0, I would to read it again.